# Javascript / CSS animation is only played once

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I made an easy css keyframes animation like this

```
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

In my HTML code, after an `onclick` I trigger  `document.getElementById(elementName).style.animation = "spin 1s";`

This works exactly one time. On the second click nothing happens.
Why? What do I have to change so the `spin` animation will be fired everytime at an onclick event?

I'm looking for a solution using in onclick where there animation will be fired every time.
I fiddled with athe style.animation parameters but don't find any solution.